# VPC to VPC connection using openVPN

Tags: amazon-ec2

am working on OpenVpn I have launched  open vpn access server in a public subnet I want to access privet subnets of another VPC Is it possible to accesif yes then how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I'll take the liberty of assuming VPC2 is running linux. Enable ipv4 forwarding, and set a `MASQUERADE` rule in the `nat` tale of `iptables` to NAT any packet from the vpn subnet going out the private subnet interface.

Routing will be a challenge. You will probably want to find someone that knows what they are doing. If you have persistent ip addresses set up correctly on the server you can use:

`dhcp "push route x.x.x.x 255.255.255.0 10.y.0.z"`

where x.x.x.x is your private network id and 10.y.0.z matches the vpn assigned ip of the second VPC.

---

If that is not an option you are looking at running a real routing protocol or assigning static routes via the VPC2 vpn ip address on all required clients.

---

In the long run it would probably be easier to run the `server side` openvpn server on VPC2 so that you can directly push routes via the config, have a static ip, and masquerade as needed.

You can also do this with bridging, but you'll need someone that understands routing to a fairly in depth degree and even the trivial implementations become complex rapidly.

The **main** thing, is that once the connection is made, each node must have a `route` to every other node it needs to communicate with.

If you manage to get all of the routing working and you see weird connectivity issues, you are probably looking at a dual homing issue... That part gets fun. Find more information here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4420/reply-on-same-interface-as-incoming